# Errors trying to bootstrap Play! app on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, jpa, heroku, playframework

Cannot for the life of me get Heroku to build a skeleton database for my Play! app using a bootstrap.  I've got a Bootstrap job and some YAML to load the object, but I get :-

```
2011-11-26T15:48:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:33,451 INFO  ~ Starting /app
2011-11-26T15:48:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:33,454 INFO  ~ Module crud is available (/app/modules/crud)
2011-11-26T15:48:33+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:33,454 INFO  ~ Module secure is available (/app/modules/secure)
2011-11-26T15:48:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:35,179 INFO  ~ Connected to jdbc:postgresql://ec2-107-20-239-110.compute-1.amazonaws.com/qsaljordae
2011-11-26T15:48:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:35,789 WARN  ~ Defaults messsages file missing
2011-11-26T15:48:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:35,804 INFO  ~ Application 'Humbug' is now started !
2011-11-26T15:48:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:35,860 WARN  ~ Precompiled template /conf/initial-data.yml not found, trying to load it dynamically...
2011-11-26T15:48:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:35,989 DEBUG ~ select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2011-11-26T15:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:36,019 WARN  ~ SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2011-11-26T15:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:36,019 ERROR ~ ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
2011-11-26T15:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:48:36,036 ERROR ~
2011-11-26T15:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-11-26T15:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: @68gdihi6a
2011-11-26T15:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Error during job execution (Bootstrap)
2011-11-26T15:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-11-26T15:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Execution exception (In /app/Bootstrap.java around line 12)
2011-11-26T15:48:36+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeException occured : Cannot load fixture initial-data.yml: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value
```

What is the problem with the hibernate_sequence table? That's not a table/object I created.

This bootstrap process worked fine in Dev on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer was to set jpa=ddl in the config, despite the warning not to do so in production....

```
# Specify the ddl generation pattern to use. Set to none to disable it
# (default to update in DEV mode, and none in PROD mode):
jpa.ddl=update
```